# How to load HTML file with style without affecting the rest of the page styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I am creating a basic email client for myself in electron.  When I load an email, that email data needs to be displayed inside a div element that looks like this `<div id="emailDisplay"></div>`.  The only problem is that this html can contain embedded stylesheets which then affect the rest of the page.  I tried using an iframe but when one of the elements failed to load (such as an image), it caused an exception and my other needed JavaScript is never executed.  The exact error is `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.  So what I'm asking is how can I display this HTML without it affecting the rest of the document's styles or how can I catch and ignore the iframe error?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `iframe` is the way to go. The error is going to happen no matter what you use, since that's a network error and has nothing to do with code. You could try `embed` or `object` but those have the same issues as `iframe` and are harder to use.

Answer (score 1):

Only ancient email clients support running JavaScript, to do so opens so many security vulnerabilities, not advised. Iframe creates another browser context. Each browser context is a complete document environment, is not possible for the iframe CSS to affect the parent CSS.

Comment: Yes, I understand this but _my_ JavaScript isn't loaded when the get request for my image isn't loaded.

Comment: Saying you need your code to run before your image is loaded? Move the code above the image, load JavaScript in the head of the document

Comment: The JavaScript is in the head.

Comment: Can simplified relevant code be added to the question? More than happy to help, confused about the part where an image failing to load throws a JavaScript error, unless there is an onLoad handler attached that’s has some buggy code

Comment: So I figured it out but I can't leave you hanging right because you'll go mad trying to understand.  Basically, I had added a `window.onload` event at one point in my code and all my JavaScript was inside of this.  So, while the image was waiting for the GET response, the JavaScript basically was unusable.  So, I moved my JavaScript out of this window.onload and now it works perfectly because of this.  Thank for being willing to help and if you wish to discuss this further, you can add me on discord Jonah#5945.

Comment: Great! Glad this is working for you now, figured had to be some onload code! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about using a  tag within your HTML?
It would still being HTML and if you specify it to style just one tag it will work.

```
<div id="emailDisplay"></div>
<style>
    #emailDisplay {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Another way of resolving this problem is by creating encapsulated javascript components (maybe with Vue or React)

Comment: The problem with this, is there is no way to pull the style tag from the document.  I could use RegEx but the problem is I can't be 100% that it will get the style for every email.